# sketch.js text along with drawing

Tags: php, jquery, drawing

i am using `sketch.js` plugin for drawing, but now client wanted that there should be typing facility too on canvas along with drawing.
I have added a textarea and button, on button `click event` i am getting textarea value and applying `ctx.fillText(...)` Till here it is working fine, but if I draw more things it removes the text appended via `ctx.fillText(...)`.

```
<canvas id="colors_sketch" width="655" height="300"></canvas>
</div>            
<div style="background:#EEE;padding:20px;">
    <textarea id="textToAppend" rows="3" style="width:100%;"></textarea>
    <button id="btnAppendText">Append</button>
</div>
```

```
$('#colors_sketch').sketch();   

$("#btnAppendText").keyup(function(e){
    var str = $("#textToAppend").val();
    var canvas = document.getElementById("colors_sketch");
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

    ctx.fillStyle = "#3e3e3e";
    ctx.font = "16px Arial";
    ctx.fillText(str, 20, canvas.height - 50);
});
```

as much I studied `sketch.js`. `ctx.fillText()` does show text on canvas but does not append it to `sketch.actions[]` thats why on further drawing it gets `sketch.actions[]` and appends new drawing and thats why text is cleared.
It will be ok if someone can give any other alternative.